# Error while reading an Excel file using Spark Scala with filename as a parameter

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark

Can someone help me with reading excel file using Spark Scala Read API? I tried installing `com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.13.1` (from Maven) to Cluster  with Databricks Runtime 6.5 and 6.6 (Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11) but it works only if I hard-code the filepath..

```
val df = spark.read
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("sheetName", "Listing_Attributed")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .option("addColorColumns", "true") // Optional, default: false
    .option("badRecordsPath", Vars.rootSourcePath + "BadRecords/" + DataCategory)
    .option("dateFormat", "dd-MON-yy")
    .option("timestampFormat", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace",true)
    .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace",true)
    .option("escape"," ")
    .load("/ABC/Test_Filename_6.12.20.xlsx")  // hard-coded path works...
//  .load(filepath)    //Filepath is a parameter and throws error, "java.io.IOException: GC overhead limit exceeded" (edited)
```

Comment: What value your filepath contains?

Answer (score 0):

Use  .option("location",inputPath) like below

```
 val df = spark.read
        .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
        .option("sheetName", "Listing_Attributed")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("location", inputPath)
        .load()
```

Comment: When I try that I got this error , "of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CaseInsensitiveMap" When checked online, I see that it is the spark-excel version issue. Not sure if 0.13.1 is the stable version to use for Scala 2.11 ?

Comment: Yes this sipt is for 0.11 or 0.12 version.

Comment: Do you have any spaces in path

Comment: No, I don't have any spaces (at least not while testing; In reality, I do which  I will worry about this later)